# Defining methods in const and then using them in an order

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I have a page where i have written

```
const cc2= this.authService.getRoles().subscribe((data:PortalUserRoleModel[]) => {
       this.roles=data;


  });
```

and based on the data i have to call another service and fetch pages accessible

```
const cc3= this.authService.getMenu(this.role).subscribe((data:PortalMenuModel[]) => {
       this.menu=data;


  });
```

in page init i need to call both of them in order so i am using this :=
concat(cc2,cc3);
but it doesnt seem to work. It says concat does not work on subscription. What am i doing wrong and what is the correct way for this.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that both service methods are asynchronous, you will have better luck in calling both of them in order using RxJS pipeable operators:, such as `switchMap`:

```
this.authService.getRoles()
  .pipe(
    switchMap((data) => {
      this.roles=data;
      return this.authService.getMenu(this.role)
    })
  ).subscribe((data) => {
     this.menu=data;
  });
```

This will ensure that the observables from `getRoles()` is returned, before `getMenu()` is triggered.

Comment: You should `return` the `this.authService.getMenu(this.role)` inside the switchmap.

Comment: @EduardoJunior yes! That was very careless of me. Thanks for the tip! Boa!

Answer (score 0):

just use forJoin:

```
import { delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import {forkJoin,of} from 'rxjs';
const example = forkJoin(
  of('Hello'),
  of('World').pipe(delay(1000))
);
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

[learn more about rxjs and Subscriptions](https://www.learnrxjs.io/)